# Truncated text on flex-item's child messes flex-item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have This markup

```
<li>
    <img>
    <div class="texts">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
</li>
```

and this CSS

```
li{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li img{
  align-self: center;
}

li .texts{
  flex: 1;
}

li .texts h2{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

The result is gonna be an small thumbnail image and some texts beside it, i want the `.texts` element to fill the remaining horizental space and it does work fine, until i use `white-space: nowrap` on the `h2` element, when i do that it breakes everything and the `.texts` element goes to next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is 2 thing you need to do:

- the flex item `.texts` need its `min-width`, which defaults to `auto`, set to `0`, or else it won't be allowed to shrink smaller than its content, hence no *ellipsis* will be rendered.
- <strike>correct an error in your CSS, where there is no space between `li` and `.texts` in the `li.texts h2` rule, where it should be `li .texts h2` to properly target the `h2` element</strike>

*I also removed the `flex-wrap: wrap`, so that doesn't create trouble in some browsers.*

Stack snippet

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}

li img{
  align-self: center;
}

li .texts{
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

li .texts h2{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50/f00">
    <div class="texts">
      <h2>Title, long enough to break line if parent to small</h2>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one was a type mistake, the `min-width: 0` worked , thanks :)

Comment: @Amin Great...and thanks :)